# how to hide a column in dynamic scaffold in grails but that sholud be visible in edit and create page

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am new to grails, i have create a table using dynamic scaffold, now i need to hide password column in view page that is in `index.gsp` (scaffold template)
I tried like below in domain class

```
Sting password
static constraints{
  password display:false
}
```

but its hiding in all the pages(edit, create page) but I should be hide only in `index.gsp`
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use the `generate-views` command (see docs) and delete all the views except for the `index.gsp` (after you take away your constraint you added). Then you can edit the `index.gsp` to be whatever you want.

Comment: If masking the value (instead of hiding the field completely) would be enough, there is a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40774872/1004651

Answer (score 1):

Use the `generate-views` command ([see docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/generate-views.html)) and delete all the views except for the `index.gsp` (after you take away your constraint you added). Then you can edit the `index.gsp` to be whatever you want.