# How to hide password fields from Grails scaffolding views?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

According to [the docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html#_scaffolding), Grails provides a number of constraints that "have no impact on persistence but customize the scaffolding". One of them is the `password`constraint. Here's how I use it:

```
class User {

    String username
    String password

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false
        password blank: false, password: true
    }
}
```

In combination with scaffolding, this has the effect that the edit view uses a specialized password input for my password field (that's fine), but the index and show view still show the password in plain text (not fine at all). Is there a way to have the password field *only* in the create and edit views, or at least masked with an asterisk or other character on the other views? Otherwise I wonder what the real benefit of this constraint might be. I tried specifying `display: false, editable: true` as additional constraints, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by using [customized field rendering](http://grails3-plugins.github.io/fields/snapshot/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html) via the fields plugin:

- Create a folder `grails-app\views\_fields\user\password`
- Put two files in this folder: `_displayWidget.gsp` and `_displayWrapper.gsp`
- Enter `<g:each in="${0..value.length()}">&bull;</g:each>` into both files

The password field will not vanish from index and show views, but at least you won't see it's value any longer, but a mask of bullet points instead. Create and edit view still use the password input widget according to the property constraint.

Comment: If your password is stored in your database in plain text, I think you should put a fixed number of bullets, otherwise it's paradoxical because you want to hide password but you give an indication on this password (its size). But of course I hope you store an encrypted password (with bcrypt for example).